# Is fan fold insulation an acceptable underlayment for hardwood?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, underlayment

Is fan-fold insulation an acceptable underlayment for hardwood?  It is being used as a leveler from one floor level to another.

Answer (score 1):

-*Is fan fold insulation an acceptable underlayment for hardwood?*

- As a complete underlayment for snap-lock flooring, **yes** but I'd be more comfortable using rolls similar to what the manufacturers specify.
- Hardwood flooring installed traditionally with nails is to be installed directly on the subfloor. ([Rosin paper is optional](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/when-installing-hardwood-floors-should-i-use-rosin-paper-roofing-felt-or-noth))

-*But it is being used as a leveler from one floor level to another.*

- Then **no**, don't count on foam to make a good shim. Use appropriately thick plywood to shim any low areas. If 1/8" sheets would be to thick, use a planer to bevel the offending area of the floor, bringing it down to an acceptable *fudge* (the foam is for fudging any discrepancies; not a blatant mismatch of floor levels).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I'm sitting on a foam hardwood sandwich now.
The hardwood should float on the foam.
And beware of dual vapor barriers: your foam is impermeable and should probably be your only vapor barrier.